# How to identify if the element has already got addClass to it?

Tags: jquery

On click of a tag href , i am adding class dynamically as shown .

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function(e) {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var topping = '<section><a >' + name + '</a></section>';
    $(this).addClass("tpActive");
 });
```

The screen looks this way

[image]

My question if the element is already having the addClass , i need to remove addClass on that element .

As shown in the screen if the element has got class it will be in  gren color , my requirement is that if it is already in green color , i want to remove the addclass to that element .

Comment: use hasClass which returns boolean then add or remove based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function(e) {
       var name = $(this).attr("name");
       var id = $(this).attr("id");
       var topping = '<section><a >' + name + '</a></section>';
       if($(this).hasClass("tpActive"))
        {
        $(this).removeClass("tpActive");
        }
       else
        {
         $(this).addClass("tpActive");
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 3):

Then you should use [`.toggleClass(className)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className) at this context.

```
$(this).toggleClass("tpActive");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `toggleClass()`

```
$(this).toggleClass("tpActive");
```

Answer (score 0):

***Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.***

```
if($( this ).hasClass( tpActive))
{
    $(this).removeClass("tpActive");
}
```

**if element is as tpActive it will remove the class.**